# What is the best way to build php from source CentOS

Tags: php, centos

I am building php from source on a new CentOS box and as usual I have to wrangle up all the various configuration options I might need. This gets tricky because there are various extensions that I want and certain options that I always for get to put in the .configure script. Not only that but PHP 5.3 has has different defaults for various options.

Is there an interactive or annotated version of the configure script somewhere or a good set of defaults to reference?

Thanks!

Comment: i added a gist to show what i mean: https://gist.github.com/1256470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the existing PHP SRPM, update the spec with the new version, release, and tarball, and rebuild.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but there are usually a few options that you want to set when you build PHP and I was looking for guidance in that area.

Comment: My guidance is to do it as the spec file does it.